# Distinguishing repetitive code with the same implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, code-quality, source-code, readability

Given this  sample code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import blackjack.model.items.Card;

public class BlackJackPlayer extends Player {

    private double bet;

    private Hand hand01 = new Hand();
    private Hand hand02 = new Hand();


    public void addCardToHand01(Card c) {
        hand01.addCard(c);
    }

    public void addCardToHand02(Card c) {
        hand02.addCard(c);
    }

    public void bustHand01() {
        hand01.setBust(true);
    }

    public void bustHand02() {
        hand02.setBust(true);
    }

    public void standHand01() {
        hand01.setStand(true);
    }

    public void standHand02() {
        hand02.setStand(true);
    }

    public boolean isHand01Bust() {
        return hand01.isBust();
    }

    public boolean isHand02Bust() {
        return hand02.isBust();
    }

    public boolean isHand01Standing() {
        return hand01.isStanding();
    }

    public boolean isHand02Standing() {
        return hand02.isStanding();
    }

    public int  getHand01Score(){ return hand01.getCardScore(); }

    public int  getHand02Score(){ return hand02.getCardScore(); }

}
```

Is this considered as a repetitive code? providing that each method is operating a seperate field but doing the same implementation ? Note that hand01 and hand02 should be distinct.

if this is considered as repetitive code, how would I address this? providing that each hand is a seperate entity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mixing the game code with the player class. You should have a class for the player and one for the game(BlackJack). You need to start with something like this:

```
public class Player 
{
    private double bet;
    private string name;

    public Hand hand = new Hand();

    public Player(string name)
    {
         this.name = name'
    }

    public Hand getHand(){
        return hand;
    }

}

public class BlackJack
{
     private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(); ;

     public BlackJack(Player player1, Player player2)
     {
         players.add(player1);
         players.add(player2);
     }

     public void bustHand(int playerNum) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException 
     {
         players.get(playerNum).getHand().setBust(true); 
     }     

}
```

I am coding on the spot so it will not working 100% but should give you an idea

Comment: I have another class does this exact same thing, in this class I made the user have two hands just in case he is eligible for split.

Comment: You can add a list of hands to the player class like list<Hands> hands; To do that.

Comment: so it's better to have it as a list?

Comment: Yes, writing the same code over and over is real bad.